# Django Admin: column incidentreport_incidentperson.id does not exist; relation does not exist

Tags: python, django

I created many database in Incident Report but only db IncidentPerson got an error. When I open django admin it kept on sayng "ProgrammingError at /admin/incidentreport/incidentperson/
column incidentreport_incidentperson.id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "incidentreport_incidentperson"."id", "incidentreport...". Appreciate the help. Thank you

```
class IncidentPerson(models.Model):
GENDER = (
    (1, 'Female'),
    (2, 'Male'),
)

INVOLVEMENT = (
    (1, 'Pedestrian'),
    (2, 'Witness'),
    (3, 'Passenger'),
    (4, 'Driver'),
)

ID_PRESENTED = (
    (1, "Driver's License"),
    (2, 'Government'),
    (3, 'Passport'),
    (4, 'School Id'),
    (5, 'Others'),
)

INJURY = (
    (1, "Fatal"),
    (2, 'Minor'),
    (3, 'Not Injured'),
    (4, 'Serious'),
)

DRIVER_ERROR = (
    (1, "Bad Overtaking"),
    (2, 'Bad Turning'),
    (3, 'Fatigued / Asleep'),
    (4, 'Inattentive'),
    (5, 'No Signal'),
    (6, 'Too Close'),
    (7, 'Too Fast'),
    (8, 'Using Cellphone'),
)

ALCOHOL_DRUGS = (
    (1, "Alcohol Suspected"),
    (2, 'Drugs suspected'),
)

SEATBELT_HELMET = (
    (1, "Seat belt/Helmet Worn"),
    (2, 'Not worn'),
    (3, 'Not worn correctly'),
)
incident_general = models.ManyToManyField(IncidentGeneral, blank=True, null=True)
incident_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
incident_middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
incident_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
incident_age = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
incident_gender = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=GENDER, blank=True, null=True)
incident_address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
incident_involvement = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=INVOLVEMENT, blank=True, null=True)
incident_id_presented = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ID_PRESENTED, blank=True, null=True)
incident_id_number = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
incident_injury = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=INJURY, blank=True, null=True)
incident_driver_error = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=DRIVER_ERROR, blank=True, null=True)
incident_alcohol_drugs = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ALCOHOL_DRUGS, blank=True, null=True)
incident_seatbelt_helmet = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=SEATBELT_HELMET, blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Did you run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: yes did it a couple of times